# ANTLR and Empty Strings Contradictory Behavior

Tags: antlr

I fundamentally don't understand how antlr works. Using the following grammar:

```
blockcomment    :   '/\*' ANYCHARS '\*/';

ANYCHARS        :   ('a'..'z' | '\n' | 'r' | ' ' | '0'..'9')*  ;
```

I get a warning message when I compile the grammar file that says:

"non-fragment lexer rule 'ANYCHARS' can match the empty string"

Fine. I want it to be able to match empty strings as: `"/\*\*/"` is perfectly valid. But when I run `"/\*\*/"` in the TestRig I get:

missing ANYCHARS at `'*/'`

Obviously I could just change it so that `'/**/'` is handled as a special case:

```
blockcomment    :   '/\*' ANYCHARS '\*/' | '/**/';
```

But that doesn't really address the underlying issue. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? How can ANTLR raise a warning about matching empty strings and then not match them at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

```
"non-fragment lexer rule 'ANYCHARS' can match the empty string"
```

The error message hints you to make `ANYCHARS` fragment.
Empty string cannot be matched as a token, that would end up with infinitely many empty tokens anywhere in the source.

You want to make the `ANYCHARS` part of the `BLOCKCOMMENT` token, rather than a separate token.
That is basically what fragments are good for - they simplify the lexer rules, but don't produce tokens.

```
BLOCKCOMMENT : '/*' ANYCHARS '*/';
fragment ANYCHARS : ('a'..'z' | '\n' | 'r' | ' ' | '0'..'9')* ;
```

EDIT: switched parser rule `blockcomment` to lexer rule `BLOCKCOMMENT` to enable fragment usage

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get the same exact error at runtime. The warning message changed to: implicit definition of token 'ANYCHARS' in parser. So it looks like it's still trying to be a token.

Comment: As I said, fragments are not tokens, they are parts of other tokens. Therefore you cannot use a fragment in parser rule, only in another lexer rule. I would suggest changing the parser rule `blockcomment` to a lexer rule `BLOCKCOMMENT` (making the whole comment a token) and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I appreciate your help. I'm still trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

add "fragment" to ANYCHARS? It will then do what you want.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get the same exact error at runtime. The warning message changed to: implicit definition of token 'ANYCHARS' in parser. So it looks like it's still trying to be a token.

Comment: oh. sorry. make blockcomment a lexer rule not a parser rule. ;)